# How to combine two values (row) into a single row with custom value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

So I have this sample table. Contains data of what `OS` are installed of all internet shop branches.

```
ID   ShopName   PCName   OS
1    Mineski    M101     WinXP
2    Mineski    M102     WinXP
3    GameCity   G201     Win7
4    GameCity   G202     Win7
5    CyberBob   C301     WinXP
6    CyberBob   C302     Win7
```

I need to query the `OS` installed by Shop.

I can do this using this query.

```
select ShopName, OS
from ShopInv
group by ShopName, OS
```

Expected results would be:

```
ShopName    OS
CyberBob    Win7
CyberBob    WinXP
GameCity    Win7
Mineski     WinXP
```

However, I only want 1 row per shop to be listed. So in cases there are more than 1 row (due to different `OS` version installed) like the sample above. I just want to display **Mixed**.

So the result would be something like this:

```
ShopName    OS
CyberBob    Mixed
GameCity    Win7
Mineski     WinXP
```

Is this feasible on SQL Server 2008?

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a92ad4/1)

Note: I'm a bit confused on how should I state my question so please do edit it if you like. :)

Comment: GROUP BY, select case count etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `case` with `distinct` `OS` value `count` for each `ShopName` check :

```
select ShopName
     , case when count(distinct OS) > 1 then 'Mixed' else min(OS) end
from ShopInv
group by ShopName
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a92ad4/8)

Comment: you can't use IIF in sqlserver 2008. It was implemented in 2012. It can be rewritten with CASE though

Comment: @t-clausen.dk : thank you, didn't notice the version.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer to this question since my first thought is to use count(). :)

Comment: Yes, using COUNT DISTINCT is a good option. I prefer MAX and MIN, because it is easy to find a maximum or minimum in an array, but quite some work to count all distinct values, only in order to determine whether there are more than one. I must admit though that I was never able to see a real difference in execution speed, so it's just a matter of personal preference in the end.

Answer (score 4):

This is easy: As you want to have one row per shop, group by shop only. Then get the OS with an aggregate function. This can be MIN or MAX. If you detect however, that MIN <> MAX, then you must show 'Mixed' instead.

```
select 
  ShopName,
  case when MIN(OS) = MAX(OS) then MIN(OS) else 'Mixed' end as OS
from ShopInv
group by ShopName;
```

Answer (score 2):

As Mentioned in question i have given both the outputs for the expected

```
 declare @t table (Id int,Shop varchar(10),PCname varchar(10),OS Varchar(10))

    insert into @t (Id,Shop,PCname,os)values (1,'Mineski','M101','WinXP'),
    (2,'Mineski','M102','WinXP'),(3,'GameCity','G201','Win7'),
    (4,'GameCity','G202','Win7'),(5,'CyberBob','C301','WinXP'),
    (6,'CyberBob','C302','Win7')
```

**First result**

```
;with cte as (
select shop,OS,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY shop,OS ORDER BY shop ) rn from @t)
select shop,OS from cte
where rn = 1
```

**And final result set**

```
;with cte as (
select shop,OS,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY shop,OS ORDER BY shop ) rn from @t)
,CTE2 AS (
Select shop,CASE WHEN R = 1 THEN 'MIXED' ELSE OS END AS 'OS' from (
select shop,OS,count(rn)R from cte
group by Shop,OS )S )
select DISTINCT shop,OS from CTE2
```

Comment: This does not  return the requested result

Answer (score 0):

```
select Shopname,
(select case when count(shopname)>1 then 'Mixed' 
         else OS 
         from ShopInv b
         where a.shopname=b.shopname
         group by b.shopname)
from ShopInv a
```

Comment: This will return an error, you need to use an aggregate function on OS in your subselect